# Assigning a named range to array

Tags: arrays, vba

I've found something that I don't quite understand. Please help explain.

so I used this code to assign values within named ranges to an array. (see below).

```
Dim accountStructure As Variant
ReDim accountStructure(2)
accountStructure(0) = Range("namedrange1")
accountStructure(1) = Range("namedrange2")
accountStructure(2) = Range("namedrange3")
```

The code works. However, in order to call the first item in accountstructure(0) I need to type accountStructure(0)(1,1), second item accountStructure(0)(2,1) third item (0)(3,1) and so on. 
I understand why there is (0) there but I don't understand why there is always a 1 after the item number. Please help me understand this.

Comment: You can (and should for performance reasons) manipulate ranges assigning them to arrays. So, if we have any range `Dim rng as Range      Set rng=Range("A1:A10") ` We can assign `Dim arr As varient     arr=rng`  But we have to treat it as two dimensional array. Because Excel VBA does'nt "know" it is one dimensional. So we can now   `For i=1 To 10         arr(i,1) = i   Next`

Comment: thanks TSion, so it will always be 2 dimensional, just how VBA works? 
Unfortunately the namedranges are dynamic (in a table). so this way is super easy. :)

Comment: Excel is a 2 dimensional planet ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have any range

```
Dim rng as Range 
Set rng=Range("A1:A10")
```

We can assign

```
Dim arr As Variant 
arr = rng
```

But we have to treat it as two dimensional array. Because Excel VBA does'nt "know" it is one dimensional. 
So we can now

```
For i=1 To 10 
    arr(i,1) = i 
Next
```